# Is there a way to find out what Pokemon are in an area?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm new to the game and haven't picked my starter Pokemon yet. Is there a way to discover what Pokemon are in the areas I'm likely to frequent or visit soon so that I can pick the starter Pokemon I'm least likely to encounter?

I'm looking specifically for an out-of-game method, or an in-game method prior to picking your starting Pokemon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no in-game method, however it is important to note if you're searching near a body of water you will be more likely to find water type, the same is true for grass type in forest/woods and normal's in large cities.

Answer (score -1):

fastpokemap.se shows where pokemon are

Comment: Some experimentation shows that the site seems to be accurate about locations, at least.  Although, the time remaining may be off.